# Javascript and Jquery essential knowledge for beginner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, database-connection

As someone who will be working extensively with JavaScript and JQuery, I hear the community is strong so I figured I would ask what a beginner should been keen in understanding when developing mobile applications. Like any other language, I wish someone would have walked in the first day of class when programming with C and said to me, "if you don't learn everything about malloc() and free() today, you will fail!" Or when I was writing with Java and heard that private and static are essential for every function and variable too late. See what I mean about learning the most important so I don't get frustrated with the details later.
My current attempt at figuring this question out is reading a book, but like most books, they don't expect you to ask what is the high-level re-occurring concepts. I have used CSS and HTML and have not used scripts or Jquery as much when developing websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read "JavaScript the Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419857713&sr=8-1&keywords=javascript+the+good+parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

This will give you what you need for JavaScript. I don't know "the best" source for jQuery, but start here: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: I started with the pocket references. Thank you for the learn.jquery and recommendation. I think that is the book I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If your new to Javascript Syntax I would highly encourage you to check out the Code Academy's Javascript Track [here](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript).

If your new to programming in General I'd also encourage you to learn about functional programming which is very important in Javascript (Very useful especially when you start working with asyncrhonous code). A great resource for this is Eloquent Javascript. The book is posted 100% free on the authors website [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/). I'd encourage you to read chapters 1-5.